# Using split in python script correctly

Tags: python, parsing, split

Im making a program that parses .m file into .h file with rearanging some stuff in different order. Im basically new to Python, but I know other language. Program code is:

```
 with open('D:\\\toolchain\Simulink\data\\application_parameters_data.m','r') as InputFile:
            for j in InputFile:
                for k in range(2): InputFile.readline()
                with open('D:\\\toolchain\Connector\ConDataGenerated.h', 'w') as file1:
                    t1 = Template('$datatype $name $initValue $comment')
                    for i in InputFile:
                        file1.write("\n") 
                        Type = [name.strip() for name in i.split(';\n')[0].split(',')]
                        file1.write(t1.safe_substitute(datatype = Type[5], name = Type[0], initValue =Type[1], comment =Type[4]))
```

I need to change it contence divided by , between elements and ; between lines accordingly. Example of input code:

```
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeedSwt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeedPar', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'single';
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed1Swt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed1Par', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'single';
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed2Swt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed2Par', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'single';
'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedSwt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedPar', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'single';
'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedDirnSwt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedDirnPar', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';

'ManCtrlMeasPositionS1Swt', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'uint16';
'ManCtrlMeasPositionS1Par', 0, [0 1], '', 'comment', 'single';
```

Here's the thing. Script works fine until it hits the space between strings or something that it doesnt recognise, or, it works with writing only first element of string to new file, in that case it iterates through strings without problems. I think it somehow connected to compiler telling me next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\StringTemplate.py", line 16, in <module>
    file1.write(t1.safe_substitute(datatype = Type[5], name = Type[0], initValue =Type[1], comment =Type[4]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

even though file creates with this problems. example of output code:

```
'uint16' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeedSwt' 0 'comment'
'single' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeedPar' 0 'comment'
'uint16' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed1Swt' 0 'comment'
'single' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed1Par' 0 'comment'
'uint16' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed2Swt' 0 'comment'
'single' 'ManCtrlInputShaftSpeed2Par' 0 'comment'
'uint16' 'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedSwt' 0 'comment'
'single' 'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedPar' 0 'comment'
'uint16' 'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedDirnSwt' 0 'comment'
'uint16' 'ManCtrlOutputShaftSpeedDirnPar' 0 'comment'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check if your `Type` (poor choice for a variable name btw) variable actually contains 5 elements before you try to write it. If it doesn't - think of what you want to do in that case and write that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the line has a length of 5 / if it's not empty, something like:

```py
                        Type = [name.strip() for name in i.split(';\n')[0].split(',')]
                        if len(Type) > 5:
                            file1.write(t1.safe_substitute(datatype = Type[5], name = Type[0], initValue =Type[1], comment =Type[4]))
```

Comment: That actually helped thx. I dont understand reason for that behaviour though, is python just stops loop if it stumble on something unexpected?

Comment: @ДенисКозлов this happens because `Type` is a list and when you read the empty line this list probably is empty (if you put a `print(Type)` after setting it you'll see).
So, trying to get the '5' element of the list `Type[5]` will return the error "list out of range" because you're putting a index beyond the range of your list [list index out of range](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113902/list-index-out-of-range)